# What is the difference between using BITMAP::bmBits vs GetDIBits?

Tags: bitmap, gdi, getdibits

I just realized that there is `BITMAP` in GDI and then you do `GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);` in almost all of the `GetDIBits` examples. but the newly populated bmp here has a field: `bmBits`

If I already have bitmaps's bits here, why would I call `GetDIBits` once again?

Thanks,
Ali Veli

Answer (score 1):

Using `GetObject` then getting the `BITMAP::bmBits` to get the bits can only be used when the bitmap was created using `CreateDIBSection`. `GetDIBits` can also be used to change the format of the Bitmap or to change it from DDB to DIB.